Can't Mount Code Into Kubernetes Pod (with Skaffold)
I'm trying to mount my local machine code (windows 10 + Docker Desktop) to a pod (its mountning the folders but without mounting anything inside them) // test-pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: alpine
    command: ["sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 30; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/c/Users/FPCC/Desktop/web-dev/healthflow/authservice/
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /mnt/c/Users/FPCC/Desktop/web-dev/healthflow/authservice/
      type: DirectoryOrCreate

then I try (after applying the pod) to kubectl exec -it test-pod -- sh  and then I try to list what I got so I try ls mnt/c/Users/FPCC/Desktop/web-dev/healthflow/ and it result in listing the folder authservice if i try to list what inside it, it's empty (non of my host machine code (ts files) was mounted)
I tried to use pvc but the result is the same

How are you getting the code on to the Kubernetes node?  hostPath: volumes refer to the local filesystem on whatever node the Pod happens to be running on, not necessarily your local system.  (What Kubernetes setup are you using; is it actually local and can it actually see the host filesystem?)

Thank you for your response. I've tried further steps but still face the same issue.
Environment Details:

OS: Windows 10
Docker Desktop: Using WSL2 backend
Kubernetes: Running within Docker Desktop

Issue:
Mounting a local directory to a Kubernetes pod shows the directory structure but not the files inside.

**Note : **
my WSL2 (ubuntu) has access to my file system because i tried
ls /mnt/c/users
in my wsl2 terminal and it listed my users:
'All Users'   Default  'Default User'   DefaultAppPool   FPCC   Public   desktop.ini

I think I got you now
the idea is that k8s is running on my sublinux right ??
if that is the case how to solve that and mount my local machine code inside the pod to be able to continue my development and reflect code changes immediately ?
